# Rename application in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I had app lets say movies, with some models and initial south migration. Now I want to change its name to resource. So I created empty south data migration and changed all table names to relevant and then renamed app folder, app name in settings.py and all imports. It looks correct. But when I run migration I receive:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: App with label movies could not be found
```

But south mark migration as completed. What should I change to correct it?

EDIT:

Should I also rename all occurences of 'movies' in initial migration?

EDIT2:
The problem also occurs when I try to migrate over clear tables. Then south try to create tables for app movies and it is already renamed to resource.

Comment: And you renamed related data in `app_name` column of `south_migrationhistory` table?

Comment: And in `django_content_type`?

Comment: Yes I rename also content type but the problem is more significant, when I try to migrate over empty table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a hacky solution to solve this one. But I don`t see any other one. I changed initial migration so it creates resource tables not movies ones, and in migration which changes tables names I wrapped commands into

```
try..except
```

block